# аналог типа ID в swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Часто вижу в уроках и примерах код вида

```
+ (id)parameterUnitWithObject:(id)object{
```

И никак не могу понять, что значит это самое id?

Comment: id - это любой объект/класс.

Answer (score 3):

`id` - указатель на любой тип, но в отличии от `void *` он всегда указывает на объект Objective-C. Другими словами, объект типа `id` должен быть унаследован от `NSObject` или `NSProxy` (либо просто иметь все методы указанных классов - `retain`, `release`, `isa` и так далее).

Компилятор нормально воспримет каст любого ObjC объекта в id и наоборот id в любой объект objective-c. На этом принципе основываются все (или почти все) типы-контейнеры в ObjC.

Еще одна интересная особенность состоит в том, что вы можете выполнить любой известный компилятору метод на объект типа id. Например:

```
id something;
[something becomeFirstResponder];
```

К вопросу что является эквивалентом id в swift:

В swift эквивалентом `id` является тип `AnyObject` либо `AnyObject?`, если он может быть nil.

Например:

```
var something: AnyObject
```

или

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender : AnyObject) {
    print("Button was clicked", sender)
}
```

или

```
func newFunc() -> AnyObject? {
    return nil
}
```

или

```
let something = "something"
self.someMethod(something as AnyObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

id - это объект любого класса, то есть это когда в метод можно передать любой объект, но а после нужно будет сделать преобразование типа, для того, что бы вы могли посылать сообщения от этого объекта. То есть id объект - это некий объект, который может принадлежать абсолютно любому класса.